# Reference XSD inside NGSI-LD

Tags: fiware

I have an XSD (XML Schema Definition) and I want to use it as @context complementary to the default @context.
Can I reference it directly and indicate somehow that it is XML so that it can be parsed as one? If yes, how? Should I upload the XSD file somewhere?
What'd be the best way to go about it?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

And no, only json is supported by NGSI-LD.
A conversion tool, as aabella proposes would fix that problem.

Comment: However, in [that](https://fiware.github.io/tutorials.Step-by-Step/schema/en/) example in the ngsi-ld @context it references xsd. Is this valid?

Comment: Use mean as long names, uris? If so, yes, that's ok. Actually, the long names are not used by an ngsi-ld broker. The broker only makes sure it's a valid URI.